# Blazor: How to Prevent onblur Event from Closing Panel Prematurely When Clicking an Internal Button?

Tags: razor, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

We have a Blazor component that represents a slide-over panel. We want to close the panel when clicking outside of it using the onblur event. This works fine.

However, the issue we're facing is that we have a button inside the panel that when clicked, the panel loses focus which triggers the onblur event first, which closes the panel prematurely.

We don't want the onblur to occur when internal elements or buttons inside the panel is clicked.

Razor code:

```
<div class="slide-over-panel @(IsVisible ? "visible" : "")" tabindex="-1" @onblur="PanelBlurred" @ref="panelRef">
    <div class="slide-over-content">
        <!-- Panel content here -->
        <CustomButton CallBackAction="OnActionButtonClick">Action Button</CustomButton>
    </div>
</div>
```

CS Code:

```
private ElementReference panelRef;


private bool wasVisible = false;

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (IsVisible && !wasVisible)
    {
        await SetFocusOnPanel(); // Await the focus operation
    }

    wasVisible = IsVisible;
}

private async Task SetFocusOnPanel()
{
    await Task.Delay(100); // Delay to ensure rendering is complete
    await panelRef.FocusAsync();
}

private async Task PanelBlurred(FocusEventArgs e)
{
    ClosePanel();
}

private async Task OnCallToActionButtonClick()
{
    // PanelBlurred is called first causing the panel to close.
}

private async Task ClosePanel()
{
   IsVisible = false;
}
```

Css (incase if you want to quickly reproduceit)

```
.slide-over-panel {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -640px;
    width: 640px;
    height: 100%;
    transition: right 0.3s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

    .slide-over-panel.visible {
        right: 0;
    }

.slide-over-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding: 24px; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar use case and here was our solution (not my favorite result adding in additional delays but it meets the need).

In your Razor code add a mouse down event:

**@onmousedown="OnItemMouseDown"**

```
<div class="slide-over-panel @(IsVisible ? "visible" : "")" tabindex="-1" @onblur="PanelBlurred" @ref="panelRef">
<div class="slide-over-content" @onmousedown="OnItemMouseDown">
    <!-- Panel content here -->
    <CustomButton CallBackAction="OnActionButtonClick">Action Button</CustomButton>
</div>
```

In your CS file add another bool to track the item being clicked, modify the OnBlur, and add the OnItemMouseDown code:

```
private bool ItemClicked { get; set; } = false;

private async Task PanelBlurred(FocusEventArgs e)
{
    // Adjust based on use case
    await Task.Delay(100);

    if(!ItemClicked)
    {
        ClosePanel();
    }

    // reset for future clicks
    ItemClicked = false;
}

private void OnItemMouseDown()
{
    ItemClicked = true;
}
```

You may need to experiment with this to meet your use case - ours was slightly different but this is how we approached the problem with the blur firing on all clicks of child items.